# Probability of taking an object

Tags: probability

Let's say I have $N$ objects, and I can pick each object with a probability $p$.

If from the process no object is taken, then I'll take one of them randomly.
What I want to know is the final probability of an object of being taken.

By some empirical experiments, I've found out this formula, which seems to be correct:
$$
p + \frac{1-p}{N}
$$
The problem is that I don't know how to get this formula theoretically.

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the probability of taking the object in the first round, plus the probability of  taking the object in the second round if no objects are picked. These can be summed since the taking the object in the first round and taking no objects in the first round are mutually exclusive events. The formula should be:

$p + (1-p)^N / N$

With 2 objects and $p=0.5$, you have a 50% chance of picking a particular object in the first round, and a 25% chance that neither object is picked in the first round, after which you have another 50% chance of picking the original object, for a final probability of 62.5%.

Comment: Two objects, each with p = (.50) leaves no room for picking no objects.

Comment: I've found out that the script that I write to found the empirical formula had an error. By fixing it coincides with this formula.

Comment: @Bafs Each object is picked *independently* with 50% probability. There's a 25% chance both objects are picked, and a 25% chance neither is picked. Picking objects is not mutually exclusive. $N=2$ and $p=0.1$ is a valid setup for the problem, but would not make any sense under your interpretation - the way you're reading it, you'd never fail to pick an object in the first step, making the answer a rather obvious $p$.